# polar equations problem

Tags: problem-solving, polar-coordinates

Relation between Cartesian (x,y) and polar coordinates (φ,r) is given with x=rcosφ
and y=rsinφ . Calculate φ(1,3) and r (1,3) .

Comment: What do you mean Calculate? Do you mean convert? Or maybe the distance?

Comment: Do you mean calculate $\phi$ and $r$ when $(x,y)$ = $(1,3)$?  Then you'll want the formulas in a slightly different form.  $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $\tan \phi = \frac{y}{x}$

Comment: I am confused too , but probably you are right . I did not understand the text of the problem.  Thank you .

Comment: Note that the choice of $(\varphi, r)$ to produce $x = r\cos \varphi$ and $y = r\sin \varphi$ is not unique.  Note only are $\sin$ and $\cos$ periodic functions, one might replace $r$ by $-r$ and make a compensating adjustment to $\varphi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to mean convert to polar coordinates, so:

$$r(1,3)=\sqrt{1^2+3^2}=\sqrt{10}\;,\;\;\theta(1,3)=\arctan\frac31=71.565^\circ$$